# How to interact with Kubernetes on docker for desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes

One of the options to use `Kubernetes` on Windows 10 is to enable it from `Docker for Windows`.

However reading many tutorials from K8S site they manage something by using minikube - for example adding addons.

Since using the option with docker we don't have minikube.

For example, how to add addon to such instance?

Comment: addon for minikube is just "preconfigured" bunch pods, deployemnts and etc, so, for Kubernetes (Docker for Windows) you need to install it yourself, which addon do you try to enable in minikube?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten I wanted to install ingress to help with DNS translation

Comment: check this out https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ , it's a docs for installation from yaml or by using helm

Answer (score 1):

You would have to manually grab the addon YAML file and `kubectl apply -f` it. But most things have Helm charts available too so maybe just do that instead?

Comment: Helm and charts are something new to me, could you give me a short explanation of it?

Comment: That is out of scope for here.